# Python module naming

Tags: python-2.7, python-module

Using python 2.7, I'm building a package as follows:

```
mypackage/
  __init__.py
  somemodule.py
```

In `__init__.py` I have this:

```
from . import somemodule
```

In somemodule.py I have The following:

```
class SomeClass:
  pass
```

When I try and access SomeClass, it prepends the filename to the class, so it's accessible by this:

```
import mypackage
mypackage.somemodule.SomeClass
```

How can I get it so that it's accessible as follows:

```
mypackage.SomeClass
```

Without putting the class directly in `__init__.py`?

I'm sure this has been answered before, but I'm not sure how to phrase the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to import your class like

```
mymodlue.myClass
```

you have to import the class in your `__init__.py`-file first, for instance like this:

```
from someclass import myClass
```

You could even do this (just to get your head around the concept - it's actually really ugly):

```
import someclass
myClass = someclass.myClass
```

Works just as well.